# wooCommerce shipping quantity issue

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have an e-commerce website based on wooCommerce. I have some shipping restrictions with the Shipping Company.
I can only ship 6/12/18 products. For shipping currently I am using Table Rate Shipping plugin in which I have set free shipping for zone and for 6/12/18 products. With this I am using Minimum Purchase Rule for minimum 6 quantity for the cart.
But customers can add 7/8 products and shipping method is allowing it (as the minimum cart limit is 6) which should not be allowed.
So is there any way we can restrict quantity in between 6-12-18?
One more thing, when I enter straight 7/8 products it gives me shipping error as this quantity is not allowed but when I enter combination of products like 6+1/5+3 it is allowing it.

Thank you!